# join 2 tables using oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join, oracle11g

There are 2 tables with data as below. The column 'ID' is the available in both tables. can someone please help me how do i get the desired output.

Table 1:

```
ID  IND  
101 Y  
102 N
```

Table 2:

```
ID  CD  
101 A  
101 B  
101 C  
101 D  
102 A
```

Desired output:

```
ID  CD IND  
101 A  Y  
101 B   
101 C   
101 D   
102 A  N
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a join where you want to display the value of `ind` only on the first `cd` of each `id`. You can do this with the `row_number()` window function in a `case` expression:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.cd, CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN t1.ind ELSE NULL END AS ind
FROM   table1 t1
JOIN   (SELECT id, cd, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ind ORDER BY cd ASC) AS rn
        FROM table2) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
SELECT table1.ID, table2.CD, table1.IND
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.ID = table2.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would normally expect that if you had a table with a relationship in the ID column that you would want to do a simple inner join: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e8e41/5

```
select t1.id, t2.cd, t1.ind
from t1
inner join t2
on t2.id = t1.id
```

However, that wouldn't give you the result you specified. Your `IND` field would be populated for each row.

Perhaps you're looking to join only where `cd = 'A'`. I don't know the point of that, but you could do something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e8e41/12

```
select t2.id, t2.cd, coalesce(t1.ind,' ') as ind
from t2
left join t1
on t2.id = t1.id
and t2.cd = 'A'
order by id, cd
```

Or perhaps you're looking to associate the `ind` with the first `cd` of each `id`. In that case, something like this (using a common table expression) might work for you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e8e41/20

```
with cte as (
  select id, cd, row_number() over (partition by id order by cd) as rn
  from t2
)
select t1.id, cte.cd, case when rn = 1 then t1.ind else ' ' end as ind
from t1
inner join cte
on t1.id = cte.id
```